# Detecting Number, Pi and e in String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex `/(-?.?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?))/g` to capture numbers that can be negative, decimal or positive. I also want to be able to capture special symbols, specifically `πe`.

What I have tried:

- `/(-?.?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)|πe)/g`

How can I capture these two symbols an expression such as `234π2`, `43.1πe` or `3π1e43e`

Comment: *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — which language, PHP?

Comment: You're right. Apologies. Correction made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use JS.

Just use this for (negative) numbers: `/-?(\d*.)?(\d+)/`

this for your symbols: `/[πe]/`

And now we combine those two to match multiples like `234π2`.

`/((-?(\d*.)?(\d+))|([πe]))+/`

#### Fix

The pattern also matches `-1-1-1` or `.1.1.1` as pointed out by Casimir et Hippolyte. To fix this:

The first part will still be a number or symbol: `/((-?(\d*\.)?\d+)|[πe])/`.

But instead of simply using the expression repeatedly, we will use a new one that won't allow signs or decimals like `.1`: `/(((\d+\.)?\d+)|[πe])/`

Put together: `/((-?(\d*\.)?\d+)|[πe])(((\d+\.)?\d+)|[πe])*/`

(I also remove so unnecessary brackets.)

Comment: Your pattern also matches: `-1-1-1-1-1` or `.1.1.1.1.1`. Not sure that this kind of results are expected.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/OaXeWu/3) is a working regex that captures numbers, modifiers (presently +-.) and special chars in all strings and leaves the rest out. Note that your `e` may well capture inadvertent `e`s in your text. For lack of other test cases this is the best that I could do.

```
[-+.]?[πe]?\d+[πe]?
```

1. the first part is an optional modifier (from that class, zero of more times)
2. and another optional class of special chars
3. your digits, one or more times
4. final optional class of special chars, zero or more times.